# how to regenerate pagerduty integration key programmatically

Tags: pagerduty

I have integrated Jenkins CI with pagerduty. Once I do that, I can see intergration key generated.
[image]

That will be used in jenkins to send the events to pagerduty.

The requirement is to rotate the keys after some time. I want to automate this.
Is there any api to regenerate the intergration key and return the key in response to be stored in jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution here is to use the REST API -- it isn't possible to regenerate the integration key directly, but you can delete the integration and create a new one programmatically.

First fetch the [service details](https://developer.pagerduty.com/api-reference/b3A6Mjc0ODE5OA-get-a-service):

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.pagerduty.com/services/<service_id>' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <bearer_token>'
```

This will include all of the integrations on the service -- make note of the `integration_id` and the `vendor_id`.

The delete endpoint isn't documented but it does seem to exist:

```
curl --location --request DELETE 'https://api.pagerduty.com/services/<service_id>/integrations/<integration_id>' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <bearer_token>'
```

And finally you can [create the new integration](https://developer.pagerduty.com/api-reference/b3A6Mjc0ODIwMw-create-a-new-integration), using the `vendor_id` from the GET request:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.pagerduty.com/services/id/integrations \
  --header 'Accept: application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer <bearer_token>' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "integration": {
    "type": "generic_email_inbound_integration",
    "name": "Email",
    "service": {
      "id": "<service_id>",
      "type": "service_reference"
    },
    "integration_email": "my-email-based-integration@subdomain.pagerduty.com",
    "vendor": {
      "type": "vendor_reference",
      "id": "<vendor_id>"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

On doing inspect element to UI button
[image: UI button to regenerate key]

Its executing POST API:

```
https://xxxxxxx.pagerduty.com/api/v1/services/XXXXXXX/integrations/XXXXXXX/regenerate_key
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31764721)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Are you even trying to answer the question? The fact that you end in "But [I] cannot find ..." seems like you are asking for help.